# PHP Laravel shows the error "field is required" in html form

Tags: php, forms

i creted a laravel registration form.when i enter data to form and click submit it shows field is required error.what is the error i make.I created a model called Candiidate.In the migration folder there is a file called_create_candidates_table.php.I get errors

The name field is required.
The email field is required etc.there are 10 fields in the form .

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Candidate;


class RegistersController extends Controller{
  public function register(Request $request){
       $this ->validate($request,[
          ' name' => 'required',
          ' email' => 'required',
           ' password' => 'required',
           ' passwordconfirm' => 'required',
           ' dateofbirth' => 'required',
            ' gender' => 'required',
            ' country' => 'required',
            ' mobile' => 'required',
             ' address' => 'required',
             ' notification' => 'required',

    ]);
  $candidates = new Candidate;
  $candidates->name = $request ->input('name');
  $candidates->email = $request ->input('email');
  $candidates->password = $request ->input('password');
  $candidates->passwordconfirm = $request ->input('passwordconfirm');
  $candidates->dateofbirth = $request ->input('dateofbirth');
  $candidates->gender = $request ->input('gender');
  $candidates->country = $request ->input('country');
  $candidates->mobile = $request ->input('mobile');
  $candidates->address = $request ->input('address');
  $candidates->notification = $request ->input('notification');

  $candidates->save();
return redirect('/')->with('response','Register Successfully');








   }
}
```

Comment: You should display your error.

Comment: Here in your controller you had mentioned that all fields are request the validator class giving this error. its not error its validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
' name' => 'required'
```

There's space in front of all the fields. Try after removing that, it's validation error you are getting.

Comment: now i get another error2/2) QueryException

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: insert into `candidates` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `passwordconfirm`, `dateofbirth`, `gender`, `country`, `mobile`, `address`, `notification`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (mihiran, mihiran@gmail.com, 19931018, 19931018, 2017/10/18, Male, Sri lanka, 0712280395, dodamgoda, on, 2017-11-10 13:31:15, 2017-11-10 13:31:15))

Comment: APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:xmKEpp8JLLpUevgU66AnmxcynU1n5ACmbSecLyix5eY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laralogin
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

Comment: Change the username to homestead